# Understand std::map::insert & emplace with hint

Tags: c++, stl

[map insert comparison](https://quick-bench.com/q/TPL6sFV5zSlvM8HJYJfcrjNWevE)

**Question**> I try to understand the usage of `insert` & `emplace` with hint introduced to `std::map`. During the following test, it seems to me that the old fashion `insert` is fastest.
Did I do something wrong here?

Thank you

```
static void MapEmplaceWithHint(benchmark::State& state) {
    std::vector<int> v{12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
    std::map<int, int> mapInt;
    auto where(std::end(mapInt));
        
  for (auto _ : state) {
   for (const auto &n : v) { // Items in non-incremental order
        where = mapInt.emplace_hint(where, n, n+1);
    }
  }
}
BENCHMARK(MapEmplaceWithHint);

static void MapInsertWithHint(benchmark::State& state) {
    std::vector<int> v{12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
    std::map<int, int> mapInt;
    auto where(std::end(mapInt));
        
  for (auto _ : state) {
   for (const auto &n : v) { // Items in non-incremental order
        where = mapInt.insert(where, {n, n+1});
    }
  }
}
BENCHMARK(MapInsertWithHint);

static void MapInsertNoHint(benchmark::State& state) {
    std::vector<int> v{12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
    std::map<int, int> mapInt;
        
  for (auto _ : state) {
   for (const auto &n : v) { // Items in non-incremental order
        mapInt.insert({n, n+1});
    }
  }
}
BENCHMARK(MapInsertNoHint);

static void MapReverseInsertNoHint(benchmark::State& state) {
    std::vector<int> v{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12};
    std::map<int, int> mapInt;
        
  for (auto _ : state) {
   for (const auto &n : v) { // Items in incremental order
        mapInt.insert({n, n+1});
    }
  }
}
BENCHMARK(MapReverseInsertNoHint);

static void MapEmplaceNoHint(benchmark::State& state) {
    std::vector<int> v{12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};
    std::map<int, int> mapInt;
        
  for (auto _ : state) {
   for (const auto &n : v) { // Items in non-incremental order
        mapInt.emplace(n, n+1);
    }
  }
}
BENCHMARK(MapEmplaceNoHint);
```

[image]

Comment: why the hint is incorrect here? I refer to http://www.vishalchovatiya.com/using-std-map-wisely-with-modern-cpp/ May you please tell me the correct hint?

Comment: Inserts a new element to the container as close as possible to the position just before hint. The element is constructed in-place, i.e. no copy or move operations are performed. The number is in non-incremental order so I assume the hint is correct.

Comment: You did however leave it up to the compiler to optimize away the result. I therefore added `benchmark::DoNotOptimize(mapInt);` after the inserting/emplacing loop in all the tests. It didn't change the outcome though :-)

Comment: Sorry, I missed that `where` is being reassigned.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, is it because the inserted elements are too trivial so that the emplace_hint doesn't show the performance gains?

Comment: Oh, you're using the same map each time through the loop. So it's essentially testing how the functions act when they detect the key is already there and do nothing, not when inserting. That explains why the emplace versions are worse: they'll allocate a node before doing the find.

Comment: I think @aschepler is on to somehing. Making much larger vectors and also using `try_emplace` makes the result a little different

Comment: @aschepler, I am new to this benchmark test platform. When we define a variable(i.e. `std::map<int, int> mapInt;`) outside the `state`, then all functions share the same `map`?

Comment: @q0987 Yes, and you do not wish to perform many costly non-essential operation within the loop (because doing so will shadow the results), so it can be tricky. Clearing the target map in the loop, [like this](https://quick-bench.com/q/7qxTw-1g8l2opprdoO7O8zpyFSY), is pretty quick though. Using larger data sets is also useful. You should also use `benchmark::DoNotOptimize` on a variable that is the target of the whole operation so that the compiler doesn't notice that the result isn't used and throws it all away :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, let's create a dataset more meaningful than 12 integers:

```
  std::vector<int> v(10000);
  std::iota(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), 0);
```

Results from all functions are now more comparable: https://quick-bench.com/q/HW3eYL1RaFMCJvDdGLBJwEbDLdg

[image]

However, there's a worse thing. Notice that looping over `state` makes it perform the same operations several times to measure the average time. But, since you are reusing the same map, each `insert` or `emplace` after the first loop iteration is failing, so you mostly measure time of failed inserts, where `hint` doesn't help.

Test cases should look more like this:

```
  std::vector<int> v(1000);
  std::iota(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), 0);

  for (auto _ : state) {
    std::map<int, int> mapInt;
    auto where(std::end(mapInt));
        
   for (const auto &n : v) { // Items in non-incremental order
        where = mapInt.emplace_hint(where, n, n+1);
    }
  }
```

And with this, hints start to shine (had to limit data to 1000, otherwise I'd get timeouts): https://quick-bench.com/q/2cR4zU_FZ5HQ6owPj9Ka_y9FtZE
[image]

I'm not sure if the benchmarks are correct, but quick glance in the assembly suggests that inserts were not optimized altogether, so there's a chance it's good enough.

As noticed by [Ted Lyngmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7582247/ted-lyngmo), `try_emplace()` with `hint` tends to perform (slightly) better:
https://quick-bench.com/q/evwcw4ovP20qJzfsyl6M-_37HzI
[image]

Comment: Good! An even [more brootal](https://quick-bench.com/q/0ukn5msV6M8j8JldYQJgtLLehW0) diff can be shown if we clear the target map between each loop or use `try_emplace`. I'm using `try_emplace` _and_ clearing the target in the link (overkill since every `try_emplace` will succeed). Edited: Now even more clear that hinting works

Comment: @TedLyngmo Interesting, with `clear()` `emplace_hint` performs worse than `insert_hint`, but good call about `try_emplace`, it's a definite winner: https://quick-bench.com/q/nUWwVMJjpxHGLWUvGcmQlY9mrdk.

Comment: That was unexpected since both `emplace_hint` and `try_emplace` should succeed every time :-) I had the wrong sizes in the first example that you copied though. [Here's your example](https://quick-bench.com/q/evwcw4ovP20qJzfsyl6M-_37HzI) where both `makef` and `maker` creates vectors of equal size. I can't say why the diff between `emplace_hint` and `try_emplace` isn't shown here though. They used the same sized vectors in your example too.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yeah, I just noticed that and re-run the benchmark, results are now identical: https://quick-bench.com/q/_YFHh9bcshgsj6J2G5552NINtkA, and the same with 1024*1024:https://quick-bench.com/q/Qa-mfZ7ZtND8iHr11dz-gaVo7Rk No idea what happened there, maybe a hiccup of the server.

Comment: Cool. I ran a test where I cleared the map every other iteration and then the diff between the hinting versions and the non-hinting versions wasn't quite as big - but still well over 2x as fast. https://quick-bench.com/q/RDtwNm1Lokj0eY1C4s4YeBk-9XU

Comment: TBH, I wonder why `hint` doesn't help in failing case. Implementation should be able to notice that `hint->first` is the same as key and skip looking down the tree, which should be faster. Maybe it just notices that `hint` is not correct, because new element cannot be inserted in that place and then falls back to regular implementation.

Comment: It's probably what aschepler mentioned in a comment. `emplace(_hint)` constructs the node before it can insert it while `try_emplace` does not.